# Package polyglossia Error

Tags: xetex, polyglossia, arabic, bidi

I updated Mactex 2021 today and got errors:

```
1- Extra \endgroup. \begin{document}


2- Package polyglossia Error: right-to-left, but (lua)bidi package was not loaded!. \begin{document}
```

When I had a Mactex 2019, it works fine. There where no changes in the document... Is there a problem with polyglossia?

Note: the class is here [class](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/llg-at-lrbyw-at/psfbdhypykdb)
MMW

```
\documentclass[10pt,oneside]{arabic-book}
\title{اللغة العربيّة}
\author{ m}
\date{\today}
\abstract{هنا توضع المقدمة}
\listfiles
\begin{document}
\chapter{مستند يدعم الكتابة باللغة العربية}

\end{document}
```

Comment: the class will need updates for the latest latex, until then you can add `\RequirePackage[2020/01/01]{latexrelease}` as the first line of the document  to get a compatible version of latex, but I still get an error that bidi is not loaded, did this form work before?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle yes it works fine with no errors

Comment: In overleaf using textlive version 2019, it works fine

Comment: yes I think bidi package has issues, I'll look later.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I'm waiting, Thanks!

Comment: if you make the first line `\RequirePackage[2019/01/01]{latexrelease}` the polyglossia/bidi errors go,  (some errors about \acute already defined)  I

Comment: well, putting \RequirePackage[2019/01/01]{latexrelease} does nothing. I still see ``Package polyglossia Error: right-to-left, but (lua)bidi package was not loaded!. ...e *[locale=mashriq,calendar=hijri]{arabic}``

Comment: yes sorry you'll need to report this to the maintainer of bidi